# Shared Google Calendars are not synced to iOS Calendars

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, ical, google-calendar

In Google Calendar I have a shared calendar called "Public Holidays". I can see all events of this calendar in Google Calendar and macOS Calendar app:

[image]
[image]

On iOS 10, I imported the Google account with all calendars. I can see the "Public Holidays" calendar in iOS calendars list. I don't see any events of the "Public Holidays" calendar in iOS calendar view and neither in the calendar widget.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I deselect shared calendars here https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect and saved the settings. Then I select them and save it again and now it works.

Comment: This is extra frustrating after the latest (~Feb 2019) redesign, since this setting does not appear to be directly accessible from the new settings menu.